# Problem importing web3.js using wasmpack/webpack

Tags: web3.js

I am having a problem importing web3.js and other wallet-adapter components under wasmpack/webpack.  I lean heavily on the Rust side of things and am able to accomplish most things by avoiding JS completely, but when it comes to wallet-adapter there seems to only be a JS solution. I've tried in webpack 4x and 5x. As an example of the problem, I create a fresh wasmpack scaffold and add 1 line to index.js.

```
import("../pkg/index.js").catch(console.error);
import {clusterApiUrl } from '@solana/web3.js');
```

Then when I run, I get a webpack loader error. as follows:

```
ERROR in ./js/index.js 3:46
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:46)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import("../pkg/index.js").catch(console.error);
| 
> import {clusterApiUrl } from '@solana/web3.js');
```

Here is the webpack.config.js

```
odule.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: {
    index: "./js/index.js"
  },

  experiments: {
    asyncWebAssembly: true,
    //importAsync: true,
  },

  output: {
    path: dist,
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  devServer: {
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') 
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin([
      path.resolve(__dirname, "static")
    ]),

    new WasmPackPlugin({
      crateDirectory: __dirname,      
    }),
  ]
};
```

I realize that this seems more like a webpack error, but given that this will be a common problem for anyone implementing Solana apps under wasm, a solution would benefit this community.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue.  You must use require() to load the modules.  import() doesn't work.  Webpack recognizes everything correctly if you use require.

You may also encounter filesize issues for these imports, because webpack has a pretty low maximum import size by default (240kb).

you can fix this in webpack.config.js with

```
performance: {
   maxEntrypointSize: 1000000,  <--- set these to whatever size you need.
   maxAssetSize: 1000000,
},
```